# Owin.TestServer incorrectly finds multiple controllers in Web Api 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, integration-testing, owin

I am setting up integration testing for a WebApi using the in-memory Owin TestServer and am getting the error

> Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'values'.
>   This can happen if the route that services this request
>   ('api/{controller}') found multiple controllers defined with the
>   same name but differing namespaces, which is not supported

in DefaultHttpControllerTypeResolver.GetControllerTypes().

Here is a link to a [small project](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiP-fk7DNt6lrDuH5xXvSJiibnXW) that reproduces the error.

**Edit** 
In an attempt to solve the problem I have subsequently tried using plain HttpServer, HttpSelfHostServer and Owin.SelfHost in addition to Owin.TestServer but they all encounter the same problem. 
**Edit of Edit**

The pattern is, when running the tests in a batch, the first test passes but subsequent tests fail with the "Multiple types were found" error. This happens in my actual project as well as the simple repro project provided which gives exactly the same behaviour. However as you can see in the repro project provided there is only one ValuesController despite the error message claiming otherwise, and multiple controller types do not exist in my actual project either.

What I have in my main project is a base class of integration tests which can be run against an actual IIS server as well as In Memory using the Owin TestServer using derived classes. When I run the tests against IIS they all pass; when I run the tests singly using the the Owin TestServer they all pass; but when I run them as a batch in memory the first one passes but the rest always fail with the above error.

In an attempt to get a fresh TestServer prior to each test I create a new one in TestInitialize() but this does not fix the problem.

Given that all the tests pass when running against IIS, I assume they should pass when run with Owin Test Server.

Here is a summary of the relevant code :
The WebApi is a very slighly modified out of the box project created by Visual Studio 2015.

Here is the Startup class used to create Owin.TestServer

```
public class Startup
{        
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        var tracing = config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
        tracing.IsVerbose = true;
        tracing.MinimumLevel = System.Web.Http.Tracing.TraceLevel.Debug;           
        // The assembly resolver is shown below.
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new TestApiAssemblyResolver());            

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        app.UseWebApi(config);  

    }
}
```

Test initialize looks like this...

```
[TestInitialize()]
public void MyTestInitialize()
{
    server = TestServer.Create<Startup>();            
    this.HttpClient = server.HttpClient;
}
```

Here is the assembly resolver used to load the WebApi assembly into the test. Without this the tests fail with an Http NotFound error.

```
public class TestApiAssemblyResolver : DefaultAssembliesResolver
{
    public override ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        List<Assembly> baseAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList();
        var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "webapiCheck.dll");
        /*
         You can try unreferencing webapiCheck.dll from this project but it makes no difference.
         */
        //var path = @"Your path...Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApiCheck\WebApiCheck\bin\webapiCheck.dll";

        var controllersAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
        baseAssemblies.Add(controllersAssembly);
        return baseAssemblies;
    }

}
```

Here is a test method...

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetValues()
{
    uri = "api/values";
    var response = await GetAsync();            

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<string>>();
        Assert.AreEqual(2, result.Count());
    }
    else
    {
        Assert.Fail(response.ReasonPhrase);
    }

}
```

I tried replacing the DefaultHttpControllerSelector to work round the problem but encountered errors there too because base.GetControllerMapping() sometimes returns no result.

```
public class BypassCacheSelector : DefaultHttpControllerSelector
    {
        private readonly HttpConfiguration _configuration;

        public BypassCacheSelector(HttpConfiguration configuration)
            : base(configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public override HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            var path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiAssemblyLocation"];

            var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
            var types = assembly.GetTypes(); //GetExportedTypes doesn't work with dynamic assemblies
            var matchedTypes = types.Where(i => typeof(IHttpController).IsAssignableFrom(i)).ToList();

            // base.GetControllerMapping() sometimes returns no result;
            var map = base.GetControllerMapping();            

            string absPath = request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath;
            var candidateName = absPath.Substring(absPath.LastIndexOf("/")+1);
            string controllerName = null;
            foreach (var m in map)
            {
                if (candidateName.StartsWith(m.Key))
                {
                    controllerName = m.Key;
                    break;
                }                
            }

            var matchedController =
                matchedTypes.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name.ToLower() == controllerName.ToLower() + "controller");

            return new HttpControllerDescriptor(_configuration, controllerName, matchedController);
        }
    }
```

To confirm that the problem is not related to attribute routing I removed attribute routing from the repro project and indeed the problem persists: when run singly the tests pass but when run in a batch they fail with the same error.

If someone can point out how to use Owin.TestServer correctly with WebApi I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in TestApiAssemblyResolver. On the second and subsequent tests the controllersAssembly was loaded more than once into baseAssemblies and so the Controller Selector could not decide which one to pick. The solution was to check baseAssemblies and only add the controllersAssembly if it was not already in baseAssemblies.

Here is the updated code which now works fine.

```
public class TestApiAssemblyResolver : DefaultAssembliesResolver
{
    public override ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        List<Assembly> baseAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList();

        var path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiAssemblyLocation"];

        var controllersAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
        // this next line fixed the problem: the second and subsequent time
        // the controller assembly was in baseAssemblies multiple times
        // which caused the problem.
        if (!baseAssemblies.Contains(controllersAssembly))
        {
            baseAssemblies.Add(controllersAssembly);
        }            

        return baseAssemblies;
    }

}
```